# Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA

Tags: python, tensorflow

I successfully installed Tensorflow with Virtualenv. However, when I run it, I get a warning about the fact that AVX2 FMA is not used:

```
(tensorflow) MacBook-Pro-van-Niels:Tensorflow NielsRogge$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 15 2017, 17:16:57) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
>>> sess = tf.Session()
2018-07-20 12:00:37.904867: I 
tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports 
instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
>>> print(sess.run(hello))
Hello, TensorFlow!
```

I probably have to run the following command in my virtual environment:

```
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade "Download URL"
```

However, I'm unsure about the download URL I have to use from [this website](https://github.com/lakshayg/tensorflow-build).
As you can see in the code snippet above, I have Python 2.7.10 and GCC 4.2.1. I have a Macbook Pro with [the following specs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPX8h.png). My OS is Mac OS High Sierra 10.13. Is it a problem that I have Python version 2.7.10, whereas on the website Python 2.7.15 is required?

Comment: I don't think it is meant as a *warning*, just a heads-up that you may get better results with a proper build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just letting you know that your performance could be improved if compilation was optimised. In order to mute the message or add additional build support, you need to install from source. See here, [tensorflow.org/install/install_sources](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources) .